# Why is Lua designed to generate intermediate opcodes?

Tags: lua, vm-implementation

I was reading Lua's source code and surprisingly found that it was implemented to generate some odd instructions (e.g. GETUPVAL, FORLOOP, etc.) Then those opcodes are executed by a virtual machine.
Is there any benefit to do this (compared with pure AST-based interpreter?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using virtual machines is an old implementation technique for languages, dating as far back to at least UCSD Pascal, BCPL, and Smalltalk. Most scripting languages now use a virtual machine. Some use a general-purpose virtual machine. Lua uses a special purpose virtual machine that reflects the semantics of the language. Hence the specialized opcodes. Lua did introduce novelty in this area by moving in version 5.0 to a register-based virtual machine, instead of a traditional stack-based one.

Answer (score 11):

For general comparison of bytecode interpreters and abstract syntax tree interpreters, see [Wikipedia:Interpreter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_(computing)#Variations).

Lua has been using a virtual machine since its birth, and introduced a register-based virtual machine in Lua 5.0 (which is the first register-based virtual machine to have a wide use.) [The Evolution of Lua](http://www.lua.org/doc/hopl.pdf), written by the authors of Lua, provides lots of resources on that topic.

Another paper written by the authors of Lua, [The Implementation of Lua 5.0](http://www.lua.org/doc/jucs05.pdf) provides lots of details on the implementation, Chapter 7 *The Virtual Machine* would be especially helpful to you, this paper is also a great reference for reading Lua's source code.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Those papers are quite useful.